# `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Tags: reactjs

Im getting the above warning in the file. I have the following code in my `RowForm`'s `render` function:

```
const RowForm = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
            return (
                <tr key={'#'} className="addIpsetListRow">
                    <td className="col-lg-1"></td>
                    <td className="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="text"
          .................
................)
});
```

The above code simply creates a `row` of form and i have no idea what i should put as a key to make that warning go away.

Comment: You are using the same key for every row. That's why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: @MuratK. im not looping through a data structure. And i call `RowForm` component any time when user clicks on a button. How could i assign a unique id to that ?

Comment: Worst case you can generate random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no data you have to use a random number or a timestamp unfortunately. For example

```
<tr key={+new Date()} className="addIpsetListRow">
```

Comment: Im not iterating at all. That component renders after a user clicks on a button.

Comment: If you have no data you will have to use a random number or a timestamp (for example "+new Date()") unfortunately.